# Mysql Group by clause help

Tags: mysql, group-by

$construct =  "SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY nid HAVING nid>1";

```
    mytable:
+----+----------+
| id |    nid   |
+----+----------+
|  1 |     null |
|  2 |        1 |
|  3 |        1 |
|  4 |        1 |
|  5 |        2 |
|  6 |        2 |
|  7 |        3 |
|  8 |        3 |
|  9 |        4 |
| 10 |        4 |
-----------------
```

How do i GROUP BY nid except nid=1?  This is a brief example but with my code i am not getting the desired results.  Is the query correct for what i am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE nid != 1 ORDER BY nid
```

`GROUP BY` causes an *aggregate* query which you can only sensibly use with an aggregation function. For example, `SELECT COUNT(*), nid GROUP BY nid` would give you the counts of rows with a given `nid`.

*Update:* Not sure I'm understanding you, but how about this then:

```
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE nid = 1 UNION SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE nid != 1 GROUP BY nid) ORDER BY nid
```

I'm not sure it makes sense to mix aggregate and non-aggregate queries, though -- on the aggregate side you'll just end up with an indeterminate representative row of that group.

Comment: i need nid=1 results but i want to group the other matching nid's

Comment: @user: It doesn't really make sense to "group by" over some range but not over another, because one query is an aggregate and one isn't. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to have two separate queries? Maybe describe your goals (in a maximally simplified example) in more detail.

Comment: is it not possible with one query? a join query perhaps?

Comment: @user: maybe a UNION, but it just doesn't make sense, semantically. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*), nid FROM mytable where nid <> 1 GROUP BY nid;
```

or

```
SELECT count(*), nid FROM mytable where nid != 1 GROUP BY nid;
```

Not sure if you are using Oracle or MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
…
GROUP BY CASE nid WHEN 1 THEN -id ELSE nid END
…
```